# Duplicated content-type in Google Cloud application

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, http-headers

I'm encontering a problem that I have never seen.
My application is in production since 2021, but it is a few days that I'm having an issue:

- The content type that the client is receiving is `Content-Type: 'application/json,application/json'`.

The application is composed by a python Google Cloud Functions called from a NGINX proxy server.

Application code in Google Cloud Functions seems ok and should never return multiple content-type.

Comment: Did you deploy recently your app/nginx procy?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere nothing has been touched in months, and the problem is occurring for only a few days

Comment: Sounds like a Google Cloud issue. If you can open a case to the support it can help you

Comment: It seems so also for us, but Google is denying it right now.

Comment: As mentioned in the comment above, I would also recommend you to open a case with Google Cloud Support.
Here is the direct link: https://cloud.google.com/support-hub